# PHP LDAP get "Office" field from Active Directory

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I will be implementing LDAP authentication into a company web portal. Once they login, I need to retrieve the value that user has in the "Office" field (under the general tab) in Active Directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my LDAP authentication code for reference:

```
public function ldap_authentication($username, $password) {
    $connection = ldap_connect($this->HOST, $this->PORT) or die("Can't establish LDAP connection");
    ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if ($connection) {
        $bind = ldap_bind($connection, $username.$this->DOMAIN, $password) or die("Can't bind to LDAP");
        if ($bind) {
            $authenticated = true;
        } 
        else {
            $authenticated = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $authenticated = false;
    }
    ldap_unbind($connection);
    return $authenticated;
}
```

Comment: You may want to try implementing http://adldap.sourceforge.net/ that simplifies a lot interacting with AD.

Answer (score 0):

Once your bind is successful, you need to do an [ldap_search](http://php.net/ldap_search), followed by [ldap_get_entries](http://php.net/ldap_get_entries). You should find plenty of examples at the aforementioned links.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll get back with you once I find a solution.